# NSManagedObjectContext save unsuccessful, but returns nil error

Tags: macos, core-data, osx-mavericks

I am developing an OS X Application that uses a single-threaded Core Data model without nested contexts.

I am creating objects on the main thread in the defaultContext and try to save them after creation, but the save fails without returning an error. I have not overwritten any methods in my CoreData objects, but I am using the latest version of MagicalRecord.

The code that fails:

```
// pseudocode for createOrFetchWithData:inContext:
// fetch object from value in objectDict
// if(!object) create project in context
// [object importValuesForKeysWithObject:objectData] // MR method
// return object
MyObject *object = [MyObject createOrFetchWithData:objectData 
                                          inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]];
if(!object) return; // just to emphasise that I am sure the object is not nil.
[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL saveSuccessful, NSError *error) {
    if(saveSuccessful) {
       NSLog(@"yay");
    } else {
       NSLog(@"nay");
    }
}];
```

The return value of `[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext]` is not nil and I have verified that the code is executed on the main thread.

I have a relationship that isn't set in the `MyObject *object`, but it is marked as `optional` in the data model.

Any idea what might cause this simple operation to fail? I have other entities that save just fine, but this particular case fails.

Note: I am running OS X Mavericks DP 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was my misunderstanding of MagicalRecord's (and possibly CoreData's) implementation of the `save:` methods: in case there is no change to the context (`[context hasChanges] == NO`) AND the parent context (!!), the save will be aborted, and the completion block is called with `NO` for `successful` and no error object.